# Display search results in two rows

Tags: php, mysql, row

I'm making a webpage and i add it a search engine. Here is the code from the results page.

```
    $term = $_POST['term'];

    $sql = mysql_query("select * from artists2 where Fname like '%$term%' or Genre like '%$term%' or Specialty like '%$term%' order by Fname");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="550" height="200"><img src="'.$row['Bio']. '" alt="" width="150" height="200"></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="550" height="30">Name: '.$row['Fname'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="550" height="30">Genre: '.$row['Genre'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="550" height="30">Specialty: '.$row['Specialty'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';
echo '</table>';
    }
?>
```

I want the results to be shown in two rows instead of one row which is shown now.
Also each result has a picture and 3 lines of text. I want the text to be show on the right side of the picture. Not below the picture as it shows now.

**UPDATE 1**

Dainis your code was very helpful. So close to what i need. 
You code gives me this:
[image]

But i need something like, this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. That's some *seriously* outdated HTML code right there. You should *never* use `table`s for layout the way you're doing. There are *much better* ways of solving layouts like these nowadays.

Here's a JSFiddle which uses CSS for layout. The HTML in the fiddle is semantic meaning it accurately represents the data that you are displaying to your visitors (with or without sight) as well as search engines:

http://jsfiddle.net/CgbQH/

As you can see the list of search results is just that; a list. Each result has an image and a `dl` (some may argue `dl` isn't the right choice for key/value pairs though). CSS is then used to make the markup render the way you want.

Also, never *ever* stick user input (your `$_POST['term']`) directly into a query like that. Haven't you heard what happened to little Bobby Tables? http://xkcd.com/327/

Edit: I've used `column-count` to make the list render in two columns. `column-count` only works in modern browsers so if you *have to* support IE you can instead set each `li` to `float: left; width: 50%`. This will however render the items in a different order from `column-count`.

Comment: Well... Ummmmmm.. What can i say!? You are a genius!!! This helps me a lot! I also have heard about Bobby.. But this website is going to run locally on my computer. Not over the web. So it's not so serious problem "security".

Comment: :) It's always nice to help someone get started with the beauty that is CSS. Also, it's always good practice to sanitize your input. Helps you remember to do it once you're working with something that will actually go online.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove some of your  tags

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  echo '<table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="550" height="200" valign="top"><img src="'.$row['Bio']. '" alt="" width="150" height="200"></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="550" height="30" valign="top">';
  echo 'Name: '.$row['Fname'].'<br />';
  echo 'Genre: '.$row['Genre'].'<br />';
  echo 'Specialty: '.$row['Specialty'];
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</table>';
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: You wanted a picture and text to its right, which implies only one row.

Comment: also if you want several to line up, move the table tags outside the while loop, so they all stay in 1 table.

Comment: Thank you Waygood for your response but it shows the same... :/

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you want it to look like? Like this?

[image]

Then the code would be something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 40%; float: left;">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="550" height="200" align="left" valign="top"><img src="'.$row['Bio']. '" alt="" width="150" height="200"></td>';
  echo '<td width="550" height="30" align="left" valign="top">';
  echo '<p>Name: '.$row['Fname'].'</p>';
  echo '<p>Genre: '.$row['Genre'].'</p>';
  echo '<p>Specialty: '.$row['Specialty'].'</p>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: In that case put the table echo inside the loop and add  style="width: 40%; float: left;" to table:

echo '<table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 40%; float: left;" >';

Comment: Muuuuuch better!!! :D thaaanks! But there is still a big space between Genre and Specialty. Also when the name is large, the results are not aligned, some gos right, and some others left.

Comment: Here, this might be better. How you format it now is basically up to you. Add some css to it and make it shine.

Comment: Ah... there is something else more... How can i make the 'Name' to be a link and when i click it, redirect me to another page with more info about this person which i clicked? I'm thinking about a new page which will auto fill with data from mysql database with the name i click each time.